# What is the best way to display a cut scene?

Tags: ios, marmalade, cutscene

How do we show cutscene in the game? Currently I am using images and animation upon them to show cutscenes or story. I heard from my friend that showing a video might be one of the option too.
Is it a good option or is there any other option except those two? I'd also like to know pros and cons of each option if you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what kind of cutscene you want. Some games have a comic book style cutscene where images would be the best option. Unless you're trying to actually make a 30 fps video out of images. Then a video would be the way to go. A third option is to actually do it in game by using the character models and animating those. This gives a smooth transition (unless you want the cutscene to be higher quality). My bro said the advantage is that this is dynamic. For example if the player is holding something he will keep holding it. Unlike a video which doesn't change.

Comment: My game cutscene just comes in start and there are just comic book style images in it, but at some places it animates some images like changing positions etc. I am doing it via changing image sequesnces and using animation handlers. I was just wondering whether there're more sophisticated method to do it or not.

Comment: @Creator What exactly do you mean by "changing image sequences"? Are you saying that your animating each object as individual images or are you showing each frame as one picture and making a movie out of it?

Comment: Both!! I am showing a picture in each frame and after some seconds change it to have a comic book effect. I am also animating some small images which looks like vibration.

Comment: Ok so what it sounds like to me is that you have a background and then some other objects that you animate separately to make it look more interesting. If that's the case and you're happy with how it looks and you can't think of any other way to do it I think you have the best option. If you go with a video and you make a mistake like maybe one of the moving objects moved too soon. Then instead of having to go into the movie, edit, and re export, all you have to do is change one line of code.