# Best way to do "cutscenes"

Tags: javascript, html-canvas, cutscene

I'm curious about the best way to display cutscenes in canvas. When I say cutscene I mean something like a static image fading from one to the other. Would it be best to use a timeout for a certain amount of seconds then go to the next image? Alternatively, would it be better to somehow use the main loop and increment a counter? If anyone has a method they use, post an answer! :D

Comment: Do you mean 2D? If so, this is probably a dupe of: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31694/what-is-the-best-way-to-display-a-cut-scene?rq=1

Comment: "Best" is really subjective.  If it works, it works.  Code something up and see if you run into concrete problems.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use `window.setTimeout`.  Instead, use `requestAnimationFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `setInterval()` or so on for animating canvas. There is a `requestAnimationFrame()` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame)) function for this. It has better performance and more usefull in general.

Here is a good article about it: http://html5hub.com/request-animation-frame-for-better-performance

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()`, because `setTimeout()` will only run after a successful call, while `setInterval()` would just stack many unhandled calls in case one of the calls takes more time to complete before another call is made. Combine it with `requestAnimationFrame()` for even better performance plus not trying to render while the browser window is not even being shown.

This is what a standard JavaScript game loop usually looks like:

```
function getTime() {
    return new Date().getTime();
}

function loop() {
    var startTime = getTime();
    screen.update();
    var elapsedTime = getTime() - startTime;
    var interval = FRAME_DURATION - elapsedTime;
    setTimeout(onTimeout, interval);

    function onTimeout() {
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
}

function main() {
    loop();
}

main();
```

You have to issue the first call to `loop()` from `main()` (or whatever your main function is called) and then it will keep calling itself indefinitely. In the snippet above, `screen.update()` is the method for your animation. And yes, you can have a `++tick` there to increment whatever property of your animation is required to make the transition.